# How to draw this graph in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, technical-drawing

[image]

I have a problem drawing this graph in `LaTeX`, can anyone help me draw this graph? I find it hard to draw the slanted lines, and when I draw them, it was disorder. This is what I've tried:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % lattice
  \draw[->,ultra thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
  \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \node [draw,ultra thick,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,label=below:$2 \pi$,label=right:$2 \pi$] at (0.5,0.5) {};
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site (and the stackexchange in general) doesn't work well with "draw this graph with latex".  But it looks like you have an attempt that doesn't quite work.  Could you post your attempt, and we can help get it working?

Answer (score 2):

You could install locally coordinates `z=x+tau y`, i.e. the first component is multiplied by 1 and the second one by tau. To this end, one may first define tau via the "functions"

```
declare function={retau=0.9;imtau=1.2;}
```

and then set

```
y={(retau,imtau)}
```

The projection can be achieved with

```
canvas is xy plane at z=0
```

from the `3d` library. In these local coordinates you can draw a grid and a rectangle to obtain the desired result.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=1.5]
    \draw[thick,->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[above left]{$\re z$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[below right]{$\im z$};
    \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \begin{scope}[declare function={retau=0.9;imtau=1.2;},
        y={(retau,imtau)},canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \draw (-4,-4) grid (8,8);
        \draw[very thick,dot/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,inner sep=1.5pt,label=#1},fill=gray] (0,0) node[dot={below right:$0$}]{}
        -- (1,0) node[dot={below right:$1$}]{}
        -- (1,1) node[dot={above left:$\tau+1$}]{}
        -- (0,1) node[dot={above left:$\tau$}]{}
        -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]